# PHP and mysql connection not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have written following code to connect mysql in php but I am not getting output.

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "pravin";
    $mysql_conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
        if ($mysql_conn->connect_error) {
             die("Connection failed: ". $mysql_conn->connect_error);
 }

echo "Connected successfully";
$name = $_POST["microorganism"];
echo $name;
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('yieldofvanillin', $mysql_conn);
if (!$db_selected){
    die ('Can\'t use  : ' . mysql_error());
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM vanillin WHERE Microorganism = '$name' ";
$result = $mysql_query($query);
while ($line = myql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo $line["Substrate"];
    echo $line["products"];
    echo $line["Microorganism"];
    echo $line["yield"];
    echo $line["Reference"];
}

mysql_close($mysql_conn);
?>
```

The database name is "yieldofvanillin" and it has five column. I an getting output Connected successfully. After that no output. Please let me know the bug in code.

Comment: in above code you used `mysqli_` and below code you used `mysql_fetch..` . correct these errors and read manual

Comment: You're using mysql functions while you open a mysqli connection. You cannot do that.

Comment: Also make sure that when you changed correctly. either use pure OOP way or pure procedural way. Don't mix both

Comment: You are mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions (and there is also a call to `myql_fetch_array` that doesn't exist). [MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mysqlinfo.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mysqlinfo.php) are two different PHP extensions and they cannot be mixed. More than that, the former is deprecated since PHP 5.5 and removed completely from PHP 7. Forget about it. Use only [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php)

Answer (score 0):

i have remove errors. which i mention in comments. Code Reference [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php). you should read this manual (strongly recommended)

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "pravin", "yieldofvanillin");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM vanillin WHERE Microorganism = '$name' ";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["Substrate"];
        echo $row["products"];
        echo $row["Microorganism"];
        echo $row["yield"];
        echo $row["Reference"];

    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're mixing mysqli and mysql libraries.

the code should be:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "pravin";
$mysql_conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
         die("Connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
 }

echo "Connected successfully";
$name = $_POST["microorganism"];
echo $name;
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($mysql_conn,'yieldofvanillin');
if (!$db_selected){
    die ('Can\'t use  : ' . mysqli_error($mysql_conn));
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM vanillin WHERE Microorganism = '$name' ";
$result = mysqli_query( $mysql_conn,$query);
while ($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $line["Substrate"];
    echo $line["products"];
    echo $line["Microorganism"];
    echo $line["yield"];
    echo $line["Reference"];
}

mysqli_close($mysql_conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove error in your code.Read carefully php manual.

```
<?php
       $servername = "localhost";
       $username = "root";
       $password = "pravin";
      $db = "yieldofvanillin";

     // Create connection
        $mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

    /* connection string*/
     if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
       exit();
    }

     $query = "SELECT * FROM vanillin WHERE Microorganism = '$name' ";

    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {


     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo $row["Substrate"];

      }


     $result->free();
   }

 $mysqli->close();
```

?>

Your output not showing because mysql_fetch_array is not correct.Because you are mixing mysql_ and mysqli_ functions and you called myql_fetch_array that doesn't exist in mysqli. MySQL and MySQLi are two different PHP extensions and they cannot be mixed. Because the former is deprecated in mysqli

Comment: Dear sir Thanks for help but I did this n I am getting error "This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

Comment: bro check now, update my answer. this error show because php not ending and i gave you one upvote.